# Date picker not working in modal form for other records asides the first

Tags: codeigniter

so i want to update lead time which is a date value by displaying the list of records and then clicking a button to display a date in a modal form to update. This only works for the first record returned. It does not popup date for other records.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the datepicker again. if you are cloning the filed
simply initialize at the time of foucs.

```
$('body').on('focus', ".datepickernew", function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker')
            .removeData('datepicker')
            .removeAttr('id')
            .unbind()
            .datepicker({dateFormat: "dd M yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, 
 });
```